# Laravel check if attributes have products

Tags: laravel

I have model Attribute, and I have model AttributeValue. I have relation products in AttributeValues belongsToMany. I want check in model Attribute if products exists in AttributeValues. I tried:

```
public function values()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AttributeValue::class);
}

public function getProductsExistsAttribute()
{
    return $this->values->each->products()->exists();
}
```

AttributeValue model:

```
public function attribute()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class);
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_attribute_values');
}
```

But is not work. I get error: `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::exists does not exist.`. How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: There is no method `exists` on Laravel collections. See all available methods for [Laravel collections here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods).

Comment: You can check where you perform query for your records for these models